# I cannot find the posts is not defined

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I been trying to figure out where can I find this issue.

Been trying to figure Why this error happen. I'm having hard time figure this out: Can you give some advice on What I can do to debug this issue, please.

**Saying that:** `'posts' is not defined` I cannot find where the problem is at I tried scanning my code to see if missing anything but I cannot find no where.

---

[image]

```js
import * as React from "react"
import { Link, graphql } from "gatsby"
import Layout from "../components/layout"
// import Bio from "../components/bio"
import Seo from "../components/seo"
import { CoverImage, getImage } from 'gatsby-plugin-image';

  const ArticleListing = ({ data, location, nodes  }) => {
  const siteTitle = data.site.siteMetadata.title || ``
  const posts = data.allMarkdownRemark.nodes

  if (post.length === 0) { // is message tell us if there no post being display post this message.
    return (
      <div id="content">
          <Layout location={location} title={siteTitle}>
            <Seo title="All posts" />
            <p>There were no blogs found. Our team is working hard to create content you will enjoy.</p>
          </Layout>
      </div>
    )
  }

  return ( // This where you be rendering your post.
    <div id="content">
      <Layout location={location} title={siteTitle}>
        <Seo title="All posts" />
        {/* <Bio /> */}
        <ol className="inline_blog" style={{ listStyle: `none` }}>
        {posts.map(function (post) {
                const title = post.frontmatter.title || post.fields.slug;

                let image = getImage(nodes.frontmatter.featuredimage);
                let alt = post.frontmatter.title;

                return (
                    <li key={post.fields.slug}>
                        <article
                            className="post-list-item"
                            itemScope
                            itemType="http://schema.org/Article"
                        >

                            <header>
                                <div className="cover_image">
                                    <CoverImage
                                        image={image}
                                        alt={alt} />
                                </div>

                                <small>
                                    {post.frontmatter.date}
                                </small>

                                <h2 className="post_heading_title">
                                    <Link to={post.fields.slug} itemProp="url">
                                        <span
                                            itemProp="headline">
                                            {title}
                                        </span>
                                    </Link>
                                </h2>
                            </header>

                            <section>
                                <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                                    __html: post.frontmatter.description || post.excerpt,
                                }}
                                    itemProp="description" />
                            </section>
                        </article>
                    </li>
                );
            })}
        </ol>
      </Layout>
    </div>
  )
}

export default ArticleListing


        
export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query {
    site {
      siteMetadata {
        title
      }
    }

    allMarkdownRemark(
        sort: { fields: [frontmatter___date], 
    }) {
      nodes {
        id
        fields {
          slug
        }
        frontmatter {
          date(formatString: "MMMM DD, YYYY")
          title
          description
          tages
          featuredimage {
            childImageSharp {
              gatsbyImageData(
                width: 500
                blurredOptions: {width: 100}
                placeholder: BLURRED
                transformOptions: {cropFocus: CENTER}
                aspectRatio: 0.7
              )
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }    
  } 
`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using a [page query](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/querying-data/page-query/) in an `ArticleListing` component (placed inside `src/components/ArticleListing.js)`, so in a regular React component.

As you can see in the previous docs, page queries are only available in top-level components (pages or templates).

That said, you have two options depending on your use-case structure.

- Moving your `ArticleListing` component inside `src/templates`
- Use a [`ustaticQuery` hook](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/querying-data/use-static-query/) (or the traditional `StaticQuery`) to create a GraphQL query and use the same JSX structure to return the posts. Something like:

  ```
  const ArticleListing = ({ data, location, nodes  }) => {
  const siteTitle = data.site.siteMetadata.title || ``
    const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
     query {
      site {
        siteMetadata {
          title
        }
      }

      allMarkdownRemark(
          sort: { fields: [frontmatter___date], 
      }) {
        nodes {
          id
          fields {
            slug
          }
          frontmatter {
            date(formatString: "MMMM DD, YYYY")
            title
            description
            tages
            featuredimage {
              childImageSharp {
                gatsbyImageData(
                  width: 500
                  blurredOptions: {width: 100}
                  placeholder: BLURRED
                  transformOptions: {cropFocus: CENTER}
                  aspectRatio: 0.7
                )
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }    
    } 
  `)


  const posts = data.allMarkdownRemark.nodes

  if (post.length === 0) { // is message tell us if there no post being display post this message.
    return (
      <div id="content">
          <Layout location={location} title={siteTitle}>
            <Seo title="All posts" />
            <p>There were no blogs found. Our team is working hard to create content you will enjoy.</p>
          </Layout>
      </div>
    )
  }

  return ( // This where you be rendering your post.
    <div id="content">
      <Layout location={location} title={siteTitle}>
        <Seo title="All posts" />
        {/* <Bio /> */}
        <ol className="inline_blog" style={{ listStyle: `none` }}>
        {posts.map(function (post) {
                const title = post.frontmatter.title || post.fields.slug;

                let image = getImage(nodes.frontmatter.featuredimage);
                let alt = post.frontmatter.title;

                return (
                    <li key={post.fields.slug}>
                        <article
                            className="post-list-item"
                            itemScope
                            itemType="http://schema.org/Article"
                        >

                            <header>
                                <div className="cover_image">
                                    <CoverImage
                                        image={image}
                                        alt={alt} />
                                </div>

                                <small>
                                    {post.frontmatter.date}
                                </small>

                                <h2 className="post_heading_title">
                                    <Link to={post.fields.slug} itemProp="url">
                                        <span
                                            itemProp="headline">
                                            {title}
                                        </span>
                                    </Link>
                                </h2>
                            </header>

                            <section>
                                <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                                    __html: post.frontmatter.description || post.excerpt,
                                }}
                                    itemProp="description" />
                            </section>
                        </article>
                    </li>
                );
            })}
        </ol>
      </Layout>
    </div>
  )
  }

  export default ArticleListing
  ```

Comment: Okay let make sure I got this right. 1. Move the ArticleListing within the src/template and 2. Move the GraphQL on the top level of the component.

Comment: Thank you Ferran for slowly explain it to me.

Comment: You're absolutely right @BrandonPowell . That  would be a third option. You can move the GraphQL query into a top-level component and populate the `ArticleListing` with the fetched data

Comment: Another question I have moved component to the top-level but now the query that's inside of the Articicielisting is saying that is not defined and also the post is saying not defined also

Comment: If you move the component to the top-level, you need to link it via `gatsby-node.js` to tell Gatsby that it's a component. The easiest approach is using rather the `useStaticQuery` hook or just moving the query to the top-level component, the template, to avoid wrong nesting or wrapping issues

Comment: Let explain this make sure I understand clearly . So within in `gatsby-node.js` within that file you want me to move the query inside of the `gatsby-node.js` an just call the file `gatsby-node.js` within the `ArticleListing.js` file. An remove the query from the file of `ArticleListing.js`

Comment: Not at all. The idea, the simplest one is just to move the `ArticleListing` query to the relative parent one (the top level), as simple as is. Another solution is to use the `useStaticQuery` hook as I suggested, practically copy pasting the snippet above

Comment: I have done What you have told me to do? What saying is give me error message that saying that   124:14  error  'useStaticQuery' is not defined and 'post' is not defined . I have tried what you are saying trying to fixed those error message

Comment: Read the docs... `useStaticQuery` needs to be imported as any other function that doesn't belong to your domain. Test the query at the GraphiQL playground (`localhost:8000/___graphql`) and check the output

Comment: Thank you so much for push to tell me just do and look at because sometime I forget to slow down my brain just do the thing. I got now next to figure out the post is not defined so going to do from now alone see where the problem is at